# List of clients connected to Udp Server in C#

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, udp, client

I have a socket program that works with **Udp**.

I want to manage clients that connect to the server.

For example, if the clients is connected to the server, add that client to a list.
I have already done this in **Tcp** with the following code:

```
static readonly Dictionary <int, TcpClient> list_clients = new Dictionary <int, TcpClient>();
```

For example, just the client who is on the list, his messages will be written.

I compared each clients with `GetStream()`. But in Udp I do not know how to do it. Can I manage clients ?

**EDIT**

I use the following code to receive a message from the client :

```
private static UdpClient udpServer = new UdpClient(11000);
private static IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 11000);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var firstData = udpServer.Receive(ref remoteEP);
    Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(firtsData);
}
```

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: UDP is connectionless. You can certainly keep a list of clients, but you have to manually track which clients are actively sending messages, and which clients have not sent any messages (and/or received a reply) for X amount of time so you can remove them from the list.

Comment: What are the specific features of customers that can be distinguished from each other?
In Tcp they were different in stream and could be gotten with GetStream. @remy-lebeau

Comment: Since there is no stream in UDP, you can use the remote `IPEndPoint` to distinguish. Otherwise, have your UDP messages carry customer identification inside of their payload data, such as user IDs, unique session cookies, etc.

Comment: (remote IP: port) for me is always the same in UDP. The only thing I've thought about before, and you mentioned it, is to put an id or a certain amount in the messages.

Comment: "*(remote IP: port) for me is always the same in Udp*" - Why? That implies that multiple customers are running on the same remote machine, using a single UDP socket to send messages to the server. How do you expect the UDP server to send messages back to specific customers? It has to send replies back to the remote IP:port that it received messages from to begin with.  If the remote IP:port is the same for multiple customers, then it can't target replies to specific customers.

Comment: For example, on port 2222 and local IP, the value of 0.0.0.0:2222 returns.

Comment: Returns from what? On the server side, it can't see `0.0.0.0` as the remote IP of a received message, it has to be the specific IP that the message was actually sent from, local or otherwise. This implies that your code is not retrieving the IP correctly. Please [edit] your question to show some real code that you are having trouble with

Comment: even when I want to add RemoteEndPoint to a list, I encounter an Exception error.

Comment: Now you are just not making any sense.  Again, please [edit] your question to show your actual code, error messages, etc. I'm voting to close this question as off-topic until you do so.

Comment: I edited the post. You can look at it.

Comment: And? What does `remoteEP` report when `udpServer.Receive()` succeeds? It should not be reporting `0.0.0.0`. How are you testing the server exactly?

Comment: I reviewed it again. My problem was to check `UdpServer.Client.RemoteEndPoint` instead of `remoteEP`.

My only question is: is the `remoteEP` data always different? Or maybe the same ports with another client? @remy-lebeau

Comment: "*is the `remoteEP` data always different?*" - if you have multiple clients sending to your server, then yes. It represents the remote endpoint of the current packet that was just read. So if you are getting packets from more than one client at a time, `remoteEP` will toggle between them as needed

Comment: Thank you for your advice. So I can identify them with the amount of remoteEP, at a specific time that the server is active.

Answer (score 0):

this code works well for me!

Server:

```
    public partial class Server : Form
    {
        public Server()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        void Print(string message)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(message);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
            socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 55555));
            byte[] vs = new byte[100];
            EndPoint senderRemote = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);

            Dictionary<EndPoint, int> pairs = new Dictionary<EndPoint, int>();
            int id = 0;
            for (int ii = 0; ii < 5; ii++)
            {
                socket.ReceiveFrom(vs, ref senderRemote);
                if (pairs.ContainsKey(senderRemote))
                    Print(pairs[senderRemote].ToString() + " says:");
                else
                {
                    pairs.Add(senderRemote, id++);
                    Print("new sender");
                }
                Print(senderRemote.ToString());
                Print(Encoding.Unicode.GetString(vs));
                socket.SendTo(vs, senderRemote);
            }

        }
    }
```

client:

```
    public partial class Client : Form
    {
        public Client()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        Socket socket;
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            socket.Send(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("Gholamam!"));
            byte[] vs = new byte[100];
            socket.Receive(vs);
            listBox1.Items.Add(Encoding.Unicode.GetString(vs));
        }

        private void Client_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
            socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, new Random().Next(1024,65000)));
            socket.Connect(IPAddress.Loopback, 55555);
        }
    }
```

don't forget that client and server are communicating. therefore they must use compromised way to communicate. if you like to store client information, it must be constant. for this, you must `bind` it to a fixed `localEndPoint`.

you can also use the solution in the question comments: you can add an id in messages. also you can use both.

P.S.: I'm using `Socket` Class instead of `TCPClient` or `UDPClient` because i found them awkward and inconsistent in some manners.